# Table is not updating using php/mysql/ajax/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to update a table of mine using information entered by the user in a form. I went about doing this using the following code, but unfortunately the form did not react in any way when the criteria is met for the table to be updated. I also checked my table and it was not updated.

This is my HTML Code:

```
<div id="b_content">
    <form action="#" method="post" onsubmit='return account_form_modify()' >
        <div class="input"><b>E-Mail:</b> <input type="text" id="email_ipt" name="email_ipt"  style="margin-left: 78px;" /></div>
        <div class="input"><b>Password:</b> <input type="password" id="password_ipt" name="password_ipt" style="margin-left: 61px;" /></div>
        <div class="input"><b>Confirm Password:</b> <input type="password" id="cpassword_ipt"  name="cpassword_ipt" /></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Modify" id="modifyBtn" /></div>
    </form>
    <div id="div_error_box_account" >
        <?php
            isset($error) ? $s_e = $error : $s_e = "";
            echo $s_e;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Javascript Code:

```
function account_form_modify() {
    var email_ipt = document.getElementById('email_ipt');
    var password_ipt = document.getElementById('password_ipt');
    var cpassword_ipt = document.getElementById('cpassword_ipt');
    var div_error_box = 'div_error_box_account';
    div_error_box.innerHTML = '';

    if(notEmpty(email_ipt, "Please enter an E-Mail Address", div_error_box)) {
        if(emailValidator(email_ipt, "Please enter a valid E-Mail Address", div_error_box)) {
            if(notEmpty(password_ipt, "Please enter a password value", div_error_box)) {
                if(notEmpty(cpassword_ipt, "Please enter a confirmation password value", div_error_box)) {
                    if(comparePassword(password_ipt, cpassword_ipt, "Please ensure both password values match", div_error_box)) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'modify_data.php',
                            type: "POST",  
                            data: { email:email_ipt.value, password:password_ipt.value},  
                            success: function (data) {
                                //alert(data);
                                if(data == 'FALSE'){
                                  var error_box = document.getElementById(div_error_box);
                                  error_box.innerHTML = 'Your details cannot be updated! Plese try again!';
                              } else {
                                  var success_box = document.getElementById(div_error_box);
                                  success_box.innerHTML = 'Your details have successfully been updated!';
                              }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my modify_data.php file:

```
<?php
include('session.php');
include('encrypt.php');
//On submitting form below function will execute 
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]); 
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["password"]);

$password = md5($password);

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE Users SET U_EMAIL = '$email', U_PASSWORD='$password' WHERE U_ID='$_SESSION['u_id']'");

if ($query) {
    echo "TRUE";
} else {
    echo "FALSE";
}

//mysql_close ($connection); // Connection Closed
?>
```

This is my session.php file:

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';

session_start();// Starting Session
?>
```

This is my connection.php file:

```
<?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myUser";
$password = "myPass";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Any help regarding this issue would be much appreciated.

**[UPDATE]**

Upon checking the console, I can see I am receiving a 500 Internal Server Error as shown in the image below, but I am unsure why this is happening.

[500 Internal Server Error](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43854948/2016-04-27%2019_24_53-Photos.png)

**[UPDATE 2]**

I have managed to solve the issue, it was a simple issue in the way I had formatted my SQL Query. It should have been written as follows:

```
if($conn->query("UPDATE Users SET U_EMAIL='".$email."', U_PASSWORD='".$password."' WHERE U_ID=".$_SESSION['u_id']."")){
```

Comment: That's a lot of code for someone to read through. Try to test your javascript and php code isolation.

Comment: must be `document.getElementById().value`; Add `.value` to each of your document.getElementById(). So `document.getElementById('email_ipt');` would be `document.getElementById('email_ipt').value;`

Comment: Please clean up your code using some jQuery plugin . 1. use jQuery form validation plugin for validation . 2. after validate then call ajax then in ajax success get data from server and append in your table

Comment: what error you have?

Comment: And look at your database connection, you opened database object but you are using the procedural way.

Comment: Remove the outermost inverted commas in `U_ID='$_SESSION['u_id']'`

Comment: Hello all, I have tried all the methods listed here but none fixed the issue unfortunately.